# Sinatra background jobs like resque but based on sequel

Tags: ruby, sinatra, backgroundworker, resque, sequel

Are there any such delayed job gems based on sequel rather than redis or activerecord which will work under rack based apps such as those based on Sinatra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [navvy](https://github.com/jeffkreeftmeijer/navvy)  It does not depend on rails like other background libraries, and already has an adapter written for sequel